# DotNetOpenAuth - Nerddinner.com - Not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, dotnetopenauth

I have imported the nerddinner.com implementation of DotNetOpenAuth into a new asp.net mvc 3 website.

Everything shows great except, when I click on either icon (Google, Yahoo, or OpenId) nothing happens. You can check the sample app here: [Sample](http://samples.bhaidar.net/openidmvc3.zip)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was just because I missed the `jquery.cookie.js` file. It works perfect now!